# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python-3.x, xml, tensorflow, object-detection

I was trying to convert a .txt file to .xml file for using tensorflow object detection API. Below is my code to write the result to a file:

```
with open(text_file,"w") as op:

                op.write(str(class_num))                 
                op.write(" ")
                op.write(str(x_tl))
                op.write(" ")
                op.write(str(y_tl))
                op.write(" ")
                op.write(str(x_br))
                op.write(" ")
                op.write(str(y_br))
                op.write("\n")
```

When i run this, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Can someone help me.

Comment: Are you passing an already opened file object (```text_file```) to ```with open```? Check with ```type(text_file)```.

Comment: @Ashna Eldho, Can you please confirm if the error is resolved with the comment mentioned above so that we can mention it as an Answer for the benefit of the Community. If the issue still persists, you can share the Content of Text File and the format of XML File and we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error could be reproduced with the sample code mentioned below:

```
text_file = 'abc.txt'
text_file = open(text_file)
print(type(text_file))
with open(text_file,"a+") as op:
  r = op.write('\n Gurudhevobhava')
```

The error is because of the the line, `text_file = open(text_file)`, and as "neutrino_logic" rightly mentioned, `print(type(text_file))` prints `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>`.

Error can be resolved by removing the line,`text_file = open(text_file)`.

Sample working code is shown below:

```
text_file = 'abc.txt'
print(type(text_file))
with open(text_file,"a+") as op:
  r = op.write('\n Gurudhevobhava')
```

Please let me know if you face any other error, I will be happy to help you.

Happy Learning!